# Adding border to merged cell using HSSFRegionUtil (Apache POI)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI and found that when I add border to the merged cells using HSSFRegionUtil , border for only one cell is appeared.

Following is the code

```
    Region region = new Region((short)0,(short)0,(short)1,(short)0);
    sheet.addMergedRegion(region);
    HSSFRegionUtil.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM,region, sheet, workbook);
```

It only showing cell border for just one cell and not the region border. Any kind help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I don't use  HSSFRegionUtil for add a border to a merged region.
My solution is:

assuming you're merge the region from row 1, column 1, until  row 5, column 5

1) set the cellStyle to the cell 1,1

2) the write a method that copy the cell style to all the others cells.

3) merge the region

here an example:

```
    CellStyle style = defaultBorderStyle;
    Row tempRow = currentSheet.getRow(startRow);
    Cell cell = tempRow.getCell(startColumn);

    for (int i = startRow; i <= endRow; i++) {
        tempRow = currentSheet.getRow(i);

        for (int j = startColumn; j <= endColumn  ; j++) {
            tempRow.getCell(j).setCellStyle(style);
        }

    }
    sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(startRow, endRow, startColumn, endColumn));
```